# Update Array, the smart way?

Tags: ios, swift

I’m using a `struct 'xyz'` containing variables. These variables are part of an `array` '`arr_InStruct`'. A copy of '`arr_InStruct`' its used as `dataSource` in a TVC.

This is a working program but I’m not happy with the solution.

**Disadvantage 1:** I need to know the exact position (`indexPath`) of the variable within '`arr_InStruct`'

**Disadvantage 2:** becomes very crowded und unreadable
Any suggestions how to update the `array` in a smarter way?

The Data file

```
import Foundation

struct xyz {
    //-> Variablen für Array
    //didSet updates the array in struct after value of variable was changed
    static var text0:String = "Entry 0" {didSet{arr_InStruct[0][0] = text0}}//push update 'arr_InStruct' bei Änderung
    static var text1:String = "Entry 1" {didSet{arr_InStruct[0][1] = text1}}//push update 'arr_InStruct' bei Änderung
    static var text2:String = "Entry 2" {didSet{arr_InStruct[0][2] = text2}}//push update 'arr_InStruct' bei Änderung
    static var text3:String = "Entry 3" {didSet{arr_InStruct[0][3] = text3}}//push update 'arr_InStruct' bei Änderung
    //<- Variablen für Array

    //disadvantage 1: I need to know the exact position (indexPath) of the variable within 'arr_InStruct'
    //disadvantage 2: becomes very crowded und unreadable
    //is there a smarter way to archive an array update?

    //2D Array
    //es wird gefüllt mit dem Inhalt der obigen Variablen
    static var arr_InStruct:[[String]] =
    [
        [
            text0,
            text1,
            text2,
            text3,
        ]
    ]//end arr_InStruct
}//end struct xyz
```

the TVC

```
import UIKit

class reloadTVTest: UITableViewController {

    //MARK: - >>> Arrays w data for TV
    let arr_Header = ["Section 0"] //1D Array 

    var arr_Data  = xyz.arr_InStruct { //2D Array in 'ArrayFile.swift' -> struct 'xyz'
        didSet{ //didSet will be called every time you change something in your array
            DispatchQueue.main.async {self.tableView.reloadData()} 
        }//end didSet
    }//end var
    //MARK: <<< Arrays w data for TV


    //MARK: - >>> Actions
    @IBAction func changePressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        print("""

            changePressed
            arr_Data in TVC:   \(arr_Data) <- Array in TVC before change
            xyz.arr_InStruct:  \(xyz.arr_InStruct) <- Array in struct before change

            """)

        xyz.text1 = "Entry changed "+randomString(length: 3) //change Variable in 'xyz'

        print("""

            xyz.text1:   '\(xyz.text1)' <- Variable changed in struct, didset called
            xyz.arr_InStruct: \(xyz.arr_InStruct) <- Array in struct changed by didSet
            arr_Data in TVC:  \(arr_Data)  <- but Array in TVC not changed
            """)

        arr_Data  = xyz.arr_InStruct //Array changed, didset called -> reloadData()

        print("""

            arr_Data in TVC was updated
            arr_Data in TVC:  \(arr_Data) <- now Array in TVC changed, didSet updated TV
            """)
    }
    //MARK: <<< Actions


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return arr_Header.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let header = UILabel()
        header.text = arr_Header[section]
        return header
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arr_Data[section].count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellreloadTVTest", for: indexPath)
        let name = arr_Data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.textLabel?.text = name

        return cell
    }
}//end class reloadTVTest


extension reloadTVTest { //Swift 4.2, creating random String
    func randomString(length: Int) -> String {
        let letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
        return String((0..<length).map{ _ in letters.randomElement()! })
    }
}//end extension reloadTVTest
```

Result:
[changing TV entries with button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ib6Ao.gif)

Comment: What is the purpose of `arr_InStruct`? Are you trying to map a single struct to multiple table view rows?

Comment: what value you want to update for array

Comment: So basically you have two data structures and a transform from the first to the second.  And the knowledge of how the transform works is in the wrong place. Is that it?

Comment: @Paulw11: First: I’m dealing with several TVC and they have all the same structure. I only need to change the data source array (e.g. arr_Data) at begin and can keep most of the rest.
Second: The variables in struct are used in serval TV. I want a single place to update the value and an automated way to update the arrays.

Comment: @matt: I’m not sure if this is the right way. My basic objective is to change the value of a variable and update all related TV as well at the same time. Using didSet in the TCV works fine and simple, but updating the underling array (arr_inStruct) seems to be a mass. Perhaps this approach isn’t the right one.

Comment: Well I’m suggesting you are unhappy because you are using a crude push. Multiple crude pushes, one for each value. Use pull, or publish and subscribe, or use reference types so there is no work to do in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there are some issued with your `struct XYZ`,

1. There is no need to make everything `static` inside it unless you're using the same object at multiple places. Instead create a single instance of `XYZ` wherever you want to use it.
2. Instead of setting `didSet` observers to all `text0, text1, text2 and text3`, make `arr_InStruct` as a *computed property*. This way `arr_InStruct` will always return the updated values.

So, `XYZ` goes like,

```
struct XYZ {
    var text0 = "Entry 0"
    var text1 = "Entry 1"
    var text2 = "Entry 2"
    var text3 = "Entry 3"

    var arr_InStruct: [[String]] {
        return [[text0, text1, text2, text3]]
    }
}
```

Next, in your controller `reloadTVTest`, create an instance of `XYZ` and use it as a `dataSource` of your `tableView`.

```
class reloadTVTest: UITableViewController {
    let arr_Header = ["Section 0"]
    var xyz = XYZ() {
        didSet {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    //MARK: - >>> Actions
    @IBAction func changePressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        xyz.text1 = "Entry changed " + randomString(length: 3) //change Variable in 'xyz'
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return xyz.arr_InStruct[section].count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellreloadTVTest", for: indexPath)
        let name = xyz.arr_InStruct[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = name
        return cell
    }

    //rest of the code....
}
```

Comment: Or rather than converting the struct to text in an array, why not just use an array of structs, and reference the field you need?  That way if your struct changes at some later date it won't break things .

Comment: @flanker I think that's the dummy struct that OP has provided.

Comment: @pgDev I assumed it was, and that it was it was mirroring a production data structure.   However I had misread it and took the array to be outside of the struct rather a property of it.  It still seems like a strange data structure though, with the struct presenting it's values in a double-nested array.  I suspect that if that was optimised the rest of the solution would be become simpler.

Comment: @ PGDev: works, I’m impressed about the reaction speed of your all! Thanks a lot. Creating a single instance results in much simpler code.

Comment: @RvdH This is what I meant by "pull". Instead of each variable knowing its place in an array ("push"), you have an array that knows the places of the variables within it ("pull").

Comment: @matt: Honestly, It took a while to get through it. Now I understand, thanks for explanation.

Answer (score -1):

its example only

```
let newArrUsingMap = arrayToUpdate.map { $0 * 10 }
```

you can update full array like this with map funtion,please give me nore details of your question